# Using javascript, is it possible to copy to clipboard in Firefox, Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to copy to clipboard  using Javascript. With Internet Explorer it's possible using

```
 window.clipboardData.setData("Text", serialNumString);
```

Is there a similar way for copy to clipboard in Firefox and Chrome?

Comment: There is not a direct way to do it, you have to use an applet or flash that interact with the operating system's clipboard. You can try a javascript plugin at http://zeroclipboard.org/, but i didn't tested that yet .

Comment: ok thanks. is there anyother way to do in controller side?

Comment: Is the copied value used only on the same domain, and needed to paste on the control from the same website it is copied from ?